# Sample size for binary outcome and continuous (%) predictor

Tags: r, logistic, sample-size, statistical-power, sas

I have a project in which I have 60-70 samples.

Outcome = binary (positive or negative case)
Exposure = % of the time participants followed new guidelines (0-100%)
Question - would it be correct to use logistic regression to analyze this?
I am guessing a sample size of 60 or 70 is too small.

What would be the best way to calculate the sample size? Difficult to find examples where the predictor is continuous and outcome is binary.
Also generally, how would the proportion of positive cases affect the analysis? I don't expect there'll be much, if any, but would like to know how to calculate the sample size in both scenarios (regular number of positive cases and low number of positive cases). Thank you.

Comment: Please don't just blindly copy a question & repost it.  This looks really bad.

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing that out. You're right, I rushed to quickly post the question (project due soon) and didn't realize I left in other content. Fixed it.

Comment: A lot more need to be assumed/presented for a sample size to arise: power (usually set at 80%) and type I error rate (usually 5%), as well as estimated odds ratio, and baseline rate, etc. See [this](https://www.real-statistics.com/logistic-regression/logistic-regression-sample-size/) example.